# Drawing 2D lines

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, path

In this tutorial a guy draws a 2D portrait in Blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooKF4hxjaSM

The only way I can find out how to do it is by creating a Bezier and modifying it. It works but it's difficult comparing to how it works in other software.

Is there any way in Blender to just add vertices in 2D (in ortho top or side views) so a line is automatically drawn between them? It looks like this guy is doing it..

Answer (score 6):

Easy and fast : ( if you have a graphics tablet )

- Use the Grease pencil to draw
- convert it to a curve

slower method :

- Create a dummy object
- Switch to Edit mode and delete everything
- switch to the appropriate view in Orthographic mode
- Keep Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and LeftClick where you want to add the next linked vertex
  ( the new vertex will be connected to the last selected vertex )

Comment: and the guy in the tutorial is supposedly doing the second method?

Comment: @Bart yes he is ( you can set a background image to trace along )

Comment: It worths noting that in the video each object has the Caltmull-Clark Subsurf modifier to automatically smooth the final strokes.

Comment: He also uses a mirror modifier to duplicate the work to the other side. Note that he uses BI and very briefly at 1:46 you see him set the material type to wire to make it visible in the render.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

Change the bezier curve segment [Set Spline Type] to poly style.

To extend a Bezier Curve

You may select the last point then press control click.

Alternate

For getting straight line segment

If you create a new curve in edit mode. Completely select that curve or portion.
Scale X 0 (zero) .... which ever axis is best.